# Compute $\int\limits_2^4\frac{f(x)}{xf(x)+xf(\frac8x)}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Compute $\displaystyle\int_2^4\frac{f(x)}{xf(x)+xf(\frac8x)}\mathrm dx$

where $f(x)$ is a strictly positive, continuous function on the interval $[2,4]$.ok because I flew thru calculus in h.s. my ' tool shed ' on this branch of mathematics has grown sparse . I tried the substitution trick with all me heart  but still could not get to where the solver did below in saying the 2 integrals are equivalent and then the integral is readily computed with the said substitution. I tried x = 8/u

Answer (score 15):

Let $t=8/x$ then
$$I:=\int_2^4\frac{f(x)}{xf(x)+xf(8/x)}dx=\int_4^2\frac{f(8/t)}{(8/t)(f(8/t)+f(t))}d(8/t)=\int_2^4\frac{f(8/t)}{t(f(8/t)+f(t))}dt:=J.$$
On the other hand,
$$2I=I+J=\int_2^4\frac{f(x)+f(8/x)}{xf(x)+xf(8/x)}dx=\int_2^4\frac{dx}{x}=\ln(4)-\ln(2)=\ln(2).$$
Hence $I=\ln(2)/2$.

Comment: That's gotta be it ! Robert Z wins !

Comment: dear prof. Robert Z.. can you help me for ask limit Math question in stack.exchange??..Because this is so hard question for ask for me..And I can not turn the question into mathematics language..(+latex and english language)..Please..can you help me as your Little student.. :( I wrote on the paper and prepared direk link.. Can you look??.. :(

Comment: I'm actually embarrassed. I thought maybe you do not want to look. https://files.acrobat.com/a/preview/fe32c9bf-d72e-4185-9fb7-72653adae16b

Comment: @MathLife I suggest you to post a question with the above link. Explain briefly where the pdf come from.

Comment: I asked..But question closed. And I deleted. This is Adobe acrobat pdf file link. (I prepared on android with pdf app)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot express the question exactly.I hope you understand what I want to ask at the pdf.

Comment: Ohh..can you look?

Comment: @MathLife I read your pdf. I am sorry but your question is not clear to me.

Comment: Do i try to explain better??..

Comment: I have difficulty asking a question..I am so sorry..